# Accumulo Range - End Key Not Inclusive

Tags: java, accumulo

I am learning Accumulo and cannot seem to get the end key specified in a Range to be inclusive. My code is below. I have tried explicitly setting the `endKeyInclusive` to `true` in `Range`, but that didn't help.

```
BatchWriter writer = conn.createBatchWriter("table", config);

List<String> deterTimes = new ArrayList<>();

String rowId = "3015551212<ll>";
String columnFamily = "deter";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    String deterTime = "20181112:21:46:33" + i;
    deterTimes.add(deterTime);
    writer.addMutation(makeRecord(rowId, columnFamily, deterTime, "DETER" + i));                   
}

writer.flush();
writer.close();

Scanner scan = conn.createScanner("table", auths);

Key startKey = new Key(rowId.getBytes(), columnFamily.getBytes(), deterTimes.get(1).getBytes());
Key endKey = new Key(rowId.getBytes(), columnFamily.getBytes(), deterTimes.get(4).getBytes());
Range range = new Range(startKey, endKey);
if (range.isEndKeyInclusive())  System.out.println("true");
scan.setRange(range);

for (Entry<Key,Value> entry : scan) {
    Text row = entry.getKey().getRow();
    Text cq = entry.getKey().getColumnQualifier();
    Value value = entry.getValue();
    System.out.println("Fetched row " + row + " with value: " + value + ", cq=" + cq);
}
```

Output:

```
true
Fetched row 3015551212<ll> with value: DETER1, cq='20181112:21:46:331'
Fetched row 3015551212<ll> with value: DETER2, cq='20181112:21:46:332'
Fetched row 3015551212<ll> with value: DETER3, cq='20181112:21:46:333'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are constructing your end key with `( row, column family, column qualifier )` as byte arrays, and the remaining dimensions of the key `( column visibility, timestamp )` set to default values (specifically, an empty byte array and `Long.MAX_VALUE`, respectively).

The scanner will stop at that exact key, inclusively. However, your actual data entry is almost certainly not that *exact* key (you didn't provide your implementation of `makeRecord` to verify). Even if your data actually has an empty column visibility, the timestamp is almost certainly not `Long.MAX_VALUE`, but rather something you set in your `makeRecord` implementation or it was set based on the tserver's time or some table logical counter. Since the timestamp dimension of the key is ordered descending, your scanner will stop looking for data at `Long.MAX_LONG` before it reaches your entries.

This is a bit like searching a dictionary for `analogy`, but stopping when you reach `analog`: you'll miss the remaining words that begin with `analog`.

This is a common pitfall when constructing ranges based on exact keys. It is generally better to construct ranges based on rows (inclusive on rows will include the entire row), rather than keys (there is a `Range` [constructor for that](http://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.accumulo/accumulo-core/1.9.2/org/apache/accumulo/core/data/Range.html)). Or, to specify the end key so that it works exclusively. You can do this by appending a null byte to the end of your last meaningful element of the column. For example, you can do something like:

```java
Key endKey = new Key(rowId.getBytes(),
                     columnFamily.getBytes(),
                     (deterTimes.get(4) + "\0").getBytes());
Range range = new Range(startKey, true, endKey, false);
```

Another pitfall you should be careful of is using `String.getBytes()` to get your byte arrays, without specifying an encoding. It would be better to use something consistent, like `"abc".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` (I usually do a static import, though, so I can specify only `UTF_8`).

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to fully explain this, I incorrectly assumed that if I did not give specific timestamps for the Keys in a Range, that the query would not use the time portion of the stored Keys when looking for matches.  While I understand the explanation, the need to append the null byte is awkward from an API perspective.  I am querying with key range because I don't want all columns to be returned and there is no meaningful column family that can group columns for the data to be processed.

Comment: I agree it is awkward. Internally, we use an API called nextKey or followingKey (don't remember exactly) for such situations, but I'm on my phone now and unable to check whether that is exposed in the public API.

Answer (score 0):

The Range is running inclusively here but perhaps there's an issue with the values your adding to it

This would be easier to diagnose with the output but is there a chance you're expecting a deter time one higher because the array begins at zero so you see a deterTime one less than expected?

If this is not the case please share your output

Comment: Added output.  Thanks.  I should also add that I am using MiniAccumuloCluster, but I am assuming that shouldn't matter as far as Range is concerned.

Comment: It looks like the endKey you specified was returned, the 4th entry in the array has  a value of DETER3 which has been retrieved

Comment: Since the range is 1 - 4 inclusive, I would have expected 4 items returned; i.e.:
 DETER1, DETER2, DETER3, DETER4.
The 4th entry is the array is DETER4, the 0th item in the array is DETER0.